# What does splitter do in logisim?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop, logic-gates

I have just started learning logisim, so i have a very simple question. My question is what does splitter do. Whats its function and **how can we actually implement it(like on breadboard or trainer board)?**
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's an organizational thing, basically.  It takes a multi-bit bus and splits it out into individual bits.  Just a change in representation in the schematic.  There is no logical function to a splitter, only interconnect.  You would implement it on a breadboard with wires.

Comment: Actually, that's a really good analogy. A breadboard is merely a big bus. And wires connected to the breadboard does exactly the same thing as splitters.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "Library Reference" in the Menu bar of Logisim for the definition of the splitter. It's actually a very good tutorial of the thing.

It just basically allows a representation of for example 32 bits into a single wire. Just so it won't be messy. And the other components like the multiplexers in Logisim would require you to use splitters since you'll have to give it an input of 2 bits with the use of a single wire for the selector.

Also, splitters can actually be used to have an input of multiple wires representing multiple bits with an output of a single wire representing all or a part of those multiple bits. And it can also have an input of a single wire of 1 or multiple bits, and output several wires, with each wire representing one or multiple bits.

It's basically just a way to make your circuits cleaner. You can implement it with wires for breadboard, the same way you could do so for the other components in Logisim like the shifter.